# Program isn't calculating factors correctly and inputting into array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, factorization

I'm having issues with the `testPerfect` method. I need it to calculate the factors and put them into the array, then return a boolean value of `true` or `false` if the number is perfect or not. As of now the array is just getting 1,2,3...5,6,7...to whatever number was input to check.  Any suggestions?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class moo_Perfect
{
public static void main ( String args [] )
{
    int gN;
    int gP = getPerfect();
    int [] array = new int[100];
    boolean tP = testPerfect(gP, array);
    //int printFactors;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}


public static int getNum() //Get amount of numbers to check
{
Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
System.out.print( "How many numbers would you like to test? " );
int count = input.nextInt();
int perfect = 1;
boolean vN = validateNum(count, perfect);
while(!vN)
{
    System.out.print (" How many numbers would you like to test? ");
    count = input.nextInt();
    vN = validateNum(count, perfect);
}
return count;
}   

public static boolean validateNum( int count, int perfect  ) //Check if number is valid
{
if (( count <= 0) || ( perfect <= 0))

{ 
    System.out.print( "Non-positive numbers are not allowed.\n");
}



else 
{
    return true;
}
return false;


}
public static int getPerfect() //Gets the numbers to test
{
Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in );
int perfect = -1;
int count = getNum();
System.out.print("Please enter a perfect number: " );
perfect = input.nextInt();  
boolean vN = validateNum(perfect, count);
while (!vN) 
{
    System.out.print("Please enter a perfect number: ");
    perfect = input.nextInt();
    vN=validateNum(perfect, count);
}
return perfect;
}


public static boolean testPerfect( int perfect, int[] array )

{
//testPerfect(perfect, array);
int limit = perfect;
int index = 0;
for ( int i = 1; i <=limit; i++)
{
    array[index++] = i;
    perfect /= i;
}
array[index] = perfect;
int sum = 0;
for ( int i =0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    sum = sum + array[i];
}

if ( sum == perfect)
{
    int[] w = array;

    return true;        
}

else
{
    return false;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for a `List`, not an array (because you don't know how long the array should be before hand, `List`s take care of this). After you instantiate a list of integers (say, `factors`), you can change the body of your first `for`-loop to

```
if (perfect % i == 0) factors.add(i)
```

i.e. "add `i` to our list of factors only if it divides evenly into `perfect`".

---

***EDIT***: If you *have* to use an array, you could do this

```
array[i] = (perfect % i == 0) ? i : 0
```

This will place `i` in your array only if it divides `perfect`, otherwise it will place `0`. Therefore, the sum of the elements in this array will equal the sum of the factors of `perfect`.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Another thing though, it's printing the original input, IE `perfect` on there twice. For 8, it's printing [8,1,2,4...,8...]